# Will Entity Framework create objects in navigation list property on post?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, web-services, lazy-loading

Say I have an assessment that has a collection of tests among other things (one to many). Is it possible for me to create the one and the many at the same time from the client side. Should Entity Framework handle this in the web service. 
For example:

```
 public class Assessment
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string AssessmentName { get; set; }

    public DateTime AssessmentDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Test> Tests { get; set; }
}

public class Test
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string TestName { get; set; }

    public string TestDescription { get; set; }

    public DateTime TestDate { get; set; }

    public int TestScore { get; set; }

    public virtual Assessment AssessmentTest { get; set; }
 }
```

Then I try to create an assessment and send the list of tests in with it:

```
 theAssessment.Tests = new List<Test> { };
 Test test1 = new Test("Name", "Do stuff", DateTime.Now, 0);
 Test test2 = new Test("Name", "Do stuff", DateTime.Now, 0);
 theAssessment.Tests.Add(test1);
 theAssessment.Tests.Add(test2);
 //send the assessment to the db
```

... and then in the web service

```
 // POST tables/Assessment
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostAssessment(Assessment item)
    {
        Assessment current = await InsertAsync(item);
        return CreatedAtRoute("Tables", new { id = current.Id }, current);
    }
```

With the debugger I can see that the assessment with list of tests is sent to the web service (item has all of the values) but then nothing happens. I get no exception but just a "bad request" message. Am I wrong to think that EF will handle create the test objects and make the relationship or is it something else?

Comment: I think you are asking if EF can handle persisting the object graph of an `Assessment` in your call to `InsertAsync(item)`. Yes, it can.

Comment: OK, thanks - struggling with the very enlightening "Bad Request" error message.

Comment: The `Bad Request` error is most likely either your client is hitting the wrong endpoint for the data it's sending or the model binder is choking on the payload.

Comment: You can use Fiddler or a tool of your choosing to examine the response message. It will usually give you some clues. If EF was your problem, you'd be getting a `500` status code back.

Comment: Thanks, I figured out the first parts of the problem. My tests needed ids attached was the first problem, and then I had a circular reference - so used JsonIgnore to sort that out. Now I have an issue when I try to connect these entities to an existing object - I cannot insert because Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.Students'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object, but I guess that is another question.